# jquery change function doesn't work in a function

Tags: jquery, function, select, bind, onchange

si have the following script:

```
function getInputString() {
//dropdown value
$('#dropdown').bind('change', function(event) {
    var dValues = $('#dropdown:selected').val();

   //the standard form should hide if nothing is choosen
   if("" != dValues) { 
       $('.shop_search').hide();
   }else {
       $('.shop_search').show();
   }
   //if first 2 letters are not MZ cValue changes, else it is the selected one 
   if (dValues.substr(0, 2) != "MZ") {
       var cValues = "simson " + dValues;
   }else {
       var cValues = dValues;
   }
});
return cValues ;
}

function getSearchString() {        
//searchform value
$('#merkmalsuche').keyup(function () {
   var sValues = $(this).val();
}).keyup();
return sValues;
}

function generateURL() {
   var mString = getSearchString();
   var vString = getInputString();
   window.location = "http://www.akf-shop.de/tag/" + vString + " " + mString;
}

$('#merkmalsuche').submit(function() { generateURL(); });
```

There is a generated select with options, setting the first var. On change, the normal search form should hide and a mirror search form is displayed. On keyup, the entered word is the second var.

If you click on submit you now should get linked to a generated URL.
But if change a value in the select field, nothing happens.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens because calling the two functions

```
var mString = getSearchString();
   var vString = getInputString();
```

is just going to **assing the handlers ..**

Also you will have error on the page as **cValues** is not defined outside the function scope.. It will be local to the event handler ..

Answer (score 1):

Check the scope of your var, you define your var inside a function and can't be reach outside...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 
`var dValues = $('#dropdown:selected').val();` 
to `var dValues = $('#dropdown option[selected=selected]').val();` or just

```
var dValues = $('#dropdown').val();
```